# Firebase onDisconnect when turning WIFI off

Tags: firebase

I noticed when I set up an `onDisconnect()`, hit my application on a different computer, and turn the WIFI off, my db is not updated; however, it is updated when I turn the WIFI back on. This worries me because I am building an application with expected mobile users and I want to gracefully handle temporary connection drops.

On the otherhand, /.info/connected knows about the disconnection and connection immediately.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and if there is a way to prevent the disconnect from happening once connection is reestablished?

**Updated code:**

```
      var connectedRef, userRef;
      connectedRef = new Firebase('https://{fb}/.info/connected');
      userRef = new Firebase('https://{fb}/users/myUser');

      connectedRef.on('value', function (snap) {

        if (snap.val()) {
          userRef.update({ online: true });
          userRef.onDisconnect().update({ online: false }, function () {
            console.log('Turn the Wi-Fi off after seeing this log.');
          });
        }

      });
```

**Result:** The db *does not* set online to false when I turn the Wi-Fi off, unless I wait about 1 minute. The db *does* set online to false when I turn the Wi-Fi back on.

Comment: onDisconnect events are managed at the server, not at the client. They are triggered when the connection is severed and nothing about the client (other than staying connected) should affect this. However, you should monitor the success callback for your update function--that is triggered immediately and may provide clues

Comment: @Kato Ok, thanks. I checked out the onDisconnect callback and it does indeed get registered before I turn the Wi-Fi off. I realize why `userRef.onDisconnect().cancel()` does not work, but it seems odd that my update only happens once the Wi-Fi is restored. Any insight?

Comment: Is the wifi off before the onDisconnect is created? I can see why the onDisconnect would be established on reconnect, since it's inside a `.info/connected` listener. Perhaps it's not being invoked before you go offline? There's not enough code here and understanding of your environment to make an intelligent leap.

Comment: @Kato I've updated the code to (hopefully) better explain what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turning off your wifi does not close the sockets in an efficient manner. Thus, the server has to wait for the socket to time out before it can fire `onDisconnect`. Since this is an entirely server-side process, the only possible outcomes are:

1) The user isn't allowed to perform the onDisconnect op (indicated in the callback immediately upon establishing the onDisconnect)

2) The event will fire when the socket times out or disconnects (the length of time is completely up to the browser/server negotiation (1 minute is not unreasonable)

3) Some data changes in Firebase between the time of establishing onDisconnect and the event firing that makes it invalid (the security rules won't allow it because the op is no longer valid)

To see your onDisconnect() fire a bit faster, try using goOffline(), which I believe will properly close the socket connections.