# swift firebase onDisconnectRemoveValue not firing when turning off wifi

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to be able to remove a connection value from my app's real-time firebase database when they lose connection unexpectedly. This does not seem to be possible from what I have tried already.

I have tried using the "goOffline" function to properly close the sockets because from what I've heard, it doesn't close properly when you turn off your wifi.

```swift
func connect() {
    let connectionsRef = self.rootRef.child("connections")
    AF.request("https://projectname.cloudfunctions.net/Connect").response { response in
        if response.data != nil {
            if self.visiblename != nil {
                connectionsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    for value in JSON(snapshot.value!).arrayValue {
                        if value["Address"].string! == self.visiblename {
                            let connectionRef = connectionsRef.child(String(value["Index"].int!))
                            connectionRef.keepSynced(true)
                            connectionRef.onDisconnectRemoveValue()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

self.reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in
    Database.database().goOffline()
}
self.reachability.whenReachable = { _ in
    Database.database().goOnline()
}

do {
    try self.reachability.startNotifier()
} catch {}
```

It does automatically remove the value after around 60 seconds but I need my app to be able to handle any internet interruptions and remove the connection value quickly.

Also, if there is no available way to remove the value from the client when the client turns off their wifi. Is there a way to detect the disconnection from the server on the server itself? I have tried comparing date.getTime() to another date.getTime() variable that when you invoke the Connect request it updates the variable. Then the server watches but it didn't seem to work because for some reason it stopped watching the variable as soon as the client disconnected and doesn't have time to realize it. I assume this is because the server is based on cloud functions and has no reason to run when no clients are invoking it.

Comment: you guys don't have to give an answer, maybe just throw out some ideas for me to try here

Comment: You want to update a value in an online database when there is no internet connection?

Comment: the function ondisconnectremovevalue does this if you leave the app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767575/firebase-ondisconnect-when-turning-wifi-off?rq=1 this post asks about the same problem and gets an answer similar to one of my attempts but my attempt obviously didnt work

Comment: ive tried ondisconnect on the server but with no avail

Comment: @cutiko ondisconnectremovevalue connects to the database and waits for you to disconnect from the database on the server but this only becomes an issue when i turn off my wifi

Comment: That method is ment to be use for presence or clean up operations when the user close the app. But you cant send data over the internet if there is no internet. That method is not a listening to the internet connection and get triggered before the internet goes off. Even if that would work you wouldnt be able to do nothing. The user press turn off the internet, the method get triggered and then what? Nothing because there is no internet!

Comment: then is there any method that does this on the server? it seems as if ondisconnect on the server doesnt work

Comment: or maybe im doing it wrong and theres something that ondisconnect on the server needs from the client (i thought this before aswell, that is why keepsync is there but 
i learned that function is only local)

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? What has to happen when the user goes offline?

Comment: @cutiko im trying to remove the connected value from the database when the user disconnects in anyway (i.e  turning off your wifi, or any other disconnection)

Comment: @cutiko i would really appreciate the continued help